# Why do I get an exception of type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException' when I use TO_TIMESTAMP?

Tags: c#, to-timestamp

I have a form that filters/sorts data from a database and displays it in a useful format. The user is suppose to enter a date range (using 2 datetimepickers, they select a start and end date for the search) and a product model to narrow down the data.

I'm running into an issue trying to apply the date range they select to the query that pulls the data. I'm somehow messing up my To_Timestamp but I haven't been able to figure out how. I have a feeling I'm missing something really simple or fundamental if searching google didn't bring it up. What am I missing here?

For some more context, I'm taking the entered dates and parsing them as datetimes then using those datetimes in the query.
EDIT: So I did a quick check to see if the Between was my issue. I still get an error after getting rid of it. The error goes away when the Where part of the query is commented out. So there's still some issue with my To_Timestamp.
EDIT2: I attempted the parameterizing the query and ran into an issue doing so for the date range I'm using. Since the user is selected a start and a stop date for the search, there are 2 dates to set := to the datetime from the database.
The way the query is written now, I believe the date is just being overwritten. How would I go about encompassing a date range within the parameterization?

```
public static DataTable MBHQuery(string stringFrom, string stringTo, string Model)
        {
            string HString =
            @" SELECT
            HEADER_ID,
            SET model=:Model,
            series,
            short_name,
            SET published_dttm=:StringFrom,
            SET published_dttm=:StringTo,
            VALID_DTTM,
            FROM
            MBH
            WHERE
            wbh1.PUBLISHED_DTTM >= StringFrom AND
            wbh1.PUBLISHED_DTTM <= StringTo";

            DataTable Hdtbl = null;
            if(IsConnected()) {
                try {
                    string HQuery = string.Format(HString, StringFrom, StringTo, Model);
                    OracleCommand Hcmd = new OracleCommand(HQuery, gmb.ServerConnection.oracleConnection);
                    Hcmd.BindByName = true;

                    Hcmd.Parameters.Add("StringFrom", StringFrom);
                    Hcmd.Parameters.Add("StringTo", StringTo);
                    Hcmd.Parameters.Add("engineModel", engineModel);

                    OracleDataAdapter HdataAdapter = new(Hcmd);
                    Hdtbl = new DataTable("HEADER");
                    HdataAdapter.Fill(Hdtbl);
                }
                catch(Exception ex) {
                    using ExceptionDialog exDialog = new(ex);
                    exDialog.ShowDialog();
                    Hdtbl = null;
                }
            }

//This is called from a different file
public void PullDataTables_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime MBdtpFromdt = this.MBdtpFrom.Value.Date;
        DateTime MBdtpTodt = this.MBdtpTo.Value.Date;

        string MBdtpFromstr = MBdtpFromdt.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD H:mm:ss");
        string MBdtpTostr = MBdtpTodt.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD H:mm:ss");

        gmb.ServerConnection.MBHQuery(MBdtpFromstr, MBdtpTostr, Model.Text);
```

Comment: Can you share the full error?

Comment: @Mureinik I added the error and the stack trace if thats helpful as well.

Comment: the `between` operator doesn't take parentheses: `between TO_TIMESTAMP(...) AND TO_TIMESTAMP(...)`

Comment: This error shows why you *shouldn't* use string concatenation or formatting to construct SQL queries. Use a parameterized query instead and pass a proper DateTime parameter value instead of a localized string. It's actually a lot easier to use parameters instead of trying to cast, convert and quote strings

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I got rid of the between to see if that had been what was messing things up. Looks like that wasn't it though I'll parameterize the query once I figure out my to_timestamp issue.

Comment: There won't be any `timestamp` issue if you use strongly typed parameters. That's the point. You can write `PUBLISHED_DTTM  between :from and :to and engine_model = :model`, and pass the DateTime values you want as from/to parameters. The *binary* values will be sent as they are alongside the SQL text in the RPC call to the database. Even when the query gets executed, the parameter values never become part of the query itself